# Is there a way to automatically invoke a function after a package being required?

Tags: node.js

```
let foo = require("foo")
```

After `foo` been imported, I want the function `foo.init` to be invoked automatically. Is it possible?

Comment: You want `init` to be called each time the module is required or just at least once?

Comment: Does `.init()` return the initalized Object? If so you could use `let foo = require("foo").init()`

Comment: If this is *always* what you want, why not just export an initialized `foo`?

Comment: Please post your "foo" source code or a code sample.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can add end of file `foo.js`;

```
module.exports.init();
```